# Closed form for the incomplete gamma function .

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation, closed-form, gamma-function

$$
\Gamma (z) \sim z^{z - 1/2} e^{ - z} \sqrt {2\pi } \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} - \frac{{139}}{{51840z^3 }} - \frac{{571}}{{2488320z^4 }} +  \cdots } \right).
$$
Above, is a closed form for the gamma function.

Is there a closed
form for the incomplete gamma function
that is for $\Gamma(a,x)$?

Comment: That is an asymptotic approximation for the gamma function which is not an exact closed form. What do you like to have? For asymptotic expansions of the incomplete gamma function under various conditions on the parameters, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11 and https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.12

Comment: A closed form of the incomplete gamma function is one in terms of a more general function. Try to find the function [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/) and click “representations through more general functions”. You will find it is a special case of a confluent hypergeometric function and other related functions.